# Native relationship field and zoo visitor

Tags: relationships, zoo-visitor

I have channel that is called jobs which contains information about job opportunities, within that channel i would like to use the native relationship field for contacting a certain person who is a zoo_visitor member.
In the cp i can asign a person using the relationship field. Only when tempting i get no results.

I’m using this code:
I tried an other, a non zoo_visitor channel, which did work. What am i doing wrong?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="jobs" entry_id="89"  status="not closed"}

{job}

 {contact_person}
     {contact_person:member_firstname}                               
{/contact_person}
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thanks for your time
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Set the status of what you are looking for in the opening relationship tag.
For example:

```
{relationship_field status="status_name"}
...
{/relationship_field}
```

This is has been tested in EE. 4.3. Hopefully this will help with earlier versions as well.